# How can we replace a single element in an n-D Tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

If we have a 1-D Tensor, we can replace a single element with a 0-D Tensor by using `tf.scatter_update` or by unpacking, replacing, packing.

Example:

```
# Pretend x came from somewhere useful.
x = tf.Variable(0)
A = tf.Variable([1, 2, 3])
# Replace the 2 with whatever's in x
A = tf.scatter_update(A, 1, x)
```

`A` will now produce `[1, 0, 3]`.

Is it possible to do this with n-D arrays?

Example:

```
# Pretend x came from somewhere useful.
x = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
A = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(3, 3, 3, 3))
# What's the equivalent of A[1, 1, 1, 1] = x ?
```

I think I could get the desired result with a mixture of `tf.unpack`, `tf.scatter_update`, and `tf.pack`, but it'd be verbose, and we'd be replacing a (potentially large) 3-D Tensor instead of just replacing a tiny 0-D Tensor. Is there a better way?

Comment: I have a temporary solution to 2-D tensor. Firstly, use `tf.gather` to get the row that I want to update. Then, use `tf.concat` to build a new row. Finally, use `tf.scatter_update` to update the specific row. I am looking for a better way for multi-D tensor, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this efficiently, I believe you will need to write a new Op or generalize scatter_update.